# "Add New Product" option missing in google play

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I've an existing app in android play store where i would like to integrate InApp purchase feature. I've read the api and implemented this feature and uploaded new signed APK in beta testing mode. Then i've tried to create in app products in InApp product section. But i dont see any option there. Please refer the image attached below.

[image]

Comment: Did you add the BILLING permission to your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. Actually i've mistakenly added com.android.BILLING instead of com.android.vending.BILLING in manifest file.

Thank you